# Parse C# DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I got a bunch of DateTime-Strings I want to parse into a c# DateTime.

```
2009-06-18 02:10:31.296761+00
2009-06-18 02:13:34.049145+00
2009-01-06 23:52:21.510121+00
2009-06-18 02:17:57.268252+00
2010-01-22 03:31:26.512496+00
2009-06-18 01:32:37.930961+00
```

I'm currently trying to get the DateTime-Object with the following line of code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But I'm always getting a System.FormatException.

Comment: That's not ISO 8601 compliant inputs

Comment: As commented by Shaw, that is not strictly [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The standard requires a `T` in the middle rather than a SPACE. For example, `2009-06-18T02:10:31.296761+00`. A SPACE is optionally allowed only on special arrangement by both parties of the data exchange, sender and recipient.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have to do anything fancy, a simple `DateTime.Parse` works:

```
DateTime myDate1 = DateTime.Parse("2009-06-18 02:10:31.296761+00");
DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Parse("2009-06-18 02:10:31.296761+03");
```

Both lines will work and the resulting dates will take the offset into account.

The reason this works is that the format you supplied is one of the standard datetime formats, specifically [the universal sortable format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalSortable), not ISO 8601.

ISO 8601 corresponds to the [roundtrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) format and uses 'T' instead of ' ' to separate date from time.

Comment: I experienced errors when parsing an ISO8601 date with the roundtrip format ('O'). The roundtrip format seems to require a fully specified date and time, including fractional seconds (e.g. 2006-05-04T00:00:00.0000000),